# Expected value and absolute value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

The only ideas I have right now is that for all x, x <= sqrt(x), which in this case is if p is even.

And if p is equal to 1 or otherwise, it is a strict equality, although I feel like im missing something. Any suggestions on how to solve?

Comment: Have you heard of Jensen's inequality?